# Google Adwords ROI tracking with GoogleAnalyticsPlus by Fooman

Tags: google-analytics

We have a multi store sitaution where the roi is tracking sending the conversion value to google.

We pay for our google adwords in £ but for our multi store we take Euro and SEK (swedish)

Is there a way through the module or google adwords we can do the currency conversion as the GBP spend against the SEK conversion is skewing the results considerably.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the latest version of our extension? It comes with a setting
`System > Configuration > Google Api > Fooman Google Analytics+ > Convert Currency`
which sounds like it would do what you are looking for.

Comment: Great, this is what I need. Because we have a multi store, I was looking in the store configuration scope and not the global level.